# Empty set as domain(s) of function(s)

Tags: functions

As written:

Let $f\colon A\rightarrow B$. Then $f$ is surjective iff for every pair of functions $g,h\colon B\rightarrow C$, $g\circ f=h\circ f$ implies  $g=h$.

*EDIT: upon further inspection, it seems A, by itself, may not be empty (with B,C non-empty) as, if it were, then a contradiction could be reached proving the other conditional/direction, because the compositions could be equal without g,h necessarily being equal. Some implicit outcomes of the parameters of this problem (which become evident upon completing the proof) appear to be: 1) C must (at least) be a doubleton, 2) likewise for B, and 3) A must be non-empty, unless B and C are also empty. No?

Answer (score 2):

Surjective means that for every element in the codomain, there exists an element in the domain that maps to it. If the codomain is empty, then the function is [vacuously](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) surjective.

If $A$ is empty, then $f$ and $g \circ f = h \circ f$ are all empty functions and thus surjective.

If $A$ is non-empty, then $B$ and $C$ must also be non-empty to satisfy the definition of a function.

Comment: Can anyone confirm or deny the propositions in my *EDIT, please?